# How to access an specific object from other object without passing pointer to that object in java?

Tags: java, oop

I have an object say `A` that loads some data from disk and it takes a bit long time to load. Many of other objects need its methods and data so I don't want neither any time I need it create a new one nor passing it through class constructor. Is there any way to create an instance of the class `A` only once at the beginning of the running project and all the other objects have access to the object `A`?

I apologize if my question is duplicated but I don't have any idea about what keywords relate to this question to find related questions.

Comment: Are you looking for `Singleton Object` ?

Comment: You're looking for the [Singleton pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: yes I think it mean a singleton but I'm not sure. I don't want instantiate so many times that object through my project

Comment: You might use a singleton pattern as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/409524)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you are dealing with the **[Singleton Design Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm)** you should declare youre class like this:

```
public class SingleObject {

   //create an object of SingleObject
   private static SingleObject instance = new SingleObject();

   //make the constructor private so that this class cannot be
   //instantiated
   private SingleObject(){}

   //Get the only object available
   public static SingleObject getInstance(){
      return instance;
   }

   public void showMessage(){
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

And then you can use it as intended.

---

In fact the approach here is to use `static` members like this:

```
public class Vehicle {

   private static String vehicleType;

    public static String getVehicleType(){
        return vehicleType;
    }

}
```

> The `static` modifier allows us to access the variable vehicleType and the method getVehicleType() using the class name itself, as follows:

```
Vehicle.vehicleType
Vehicle.getVehicleType()
```

Take a look at **[Java static class Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-static-class-example/)** for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The design pattern is called a singleton. It could look like this:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;
    private Singleton () {}

    /*
     * Returns the single object instance to every
     * caller. This is how you can access the singleton
     * object in your whole application
     */
    public static Singleton getInstance () {
        if (Singleton.instance == null) {
            Singleton.instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return Singleton.instance;
    }
}
```

All objects can use the singleton by calling `Singleton.getInstance()`

Comment: Note that that implementation of the singleton pattern isn't thread-safe - there are various better ones. Read Effective Java for details.